# What is '??=' (Javascript, Uppy)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make my first OSS contribution (just a simple one  ...updating the nanoid dependency in Uppy since the current version has a vulnerability). I'm hoping someone who has experience with OSS, and possibly contributing to Uppy can point me in the right direction.

I got to the point of making a commit to patch update nanoid, checking that the examples still looked good, the unit tests pass, but then when I run the `yarn release` script I get a syntax error on this line.
https://github.com/transloadit/uppy/blob/main/private/release/formatChangeLog.js#L14
that says `'??=' is an unexpected token`. Does anyone have any idea about this? I'm not familiar with what '??=' even is. And googling it has virtually no results, so I'm feeling very lost.